# How to test database migrations with Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, database-migration

I want to make sure each software version could handle the DB state of the previous software version.

Migrations are tested on application startup. Currently I always test this against an empty database (which off course always works)

Previous version means:

- last build on same branch
- last build on target branch in case of a merge request

Therefore I'm looking for a solution/workflow how to handle this with gitlab CI with (selfhosted) runners (on k8s).
I'm not looking for a tool to create migrations.

Comment: It's not just sufficient to load a DB dump and run the application in a CI job for testing it?

Comment: @DavideMadrisan this is also a Approach I came up with, however gitlab ci gives you no tooling to access older builds out of the box

Comment: I do not know if an old artifact can be easily pulled from a CI job. A simpler solution can be save the dumps to an external (ftp) site and get them with a `curl` command, if the dumps cannot be pushed to the package registry.